# How to find Xpath for g class?

Tags: xpath, web, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to find xpath way to this element `<g class="highcharts-axis-labels" zIndex="7">`

I tried this and it doesn't work `g[@class='highcharts-axis-labels']`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, below is one of the ways,

```
//g[contains(@class, 'highcharts-axis-labels')]
```

or to match only the class itself,

```
//*[contains(@class, 'highcharts-axis-labels')]
```

Comment: if it helps you can very well accept it, since to avoid others attention to it

Comment: You can also use `g` instead of `*` to specifically only match `g` elements.

Comment: @JLRishe what i mentioned is one of the ways to find it. But yes to be specific i have updated my answer.